# How to get week current day in number format on solar calendar java

Tags: java

I try to get current day of the week but the result gives me that day plus one , for example if is Saturday i get 7 instead of 6.

my code :

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int ddd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
      String CurrentDay =String.valueOf(ddd);
      textView.setText(CurrentDay);
```

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise you not to use the legacy `java.util.Calendar` class.  You should instead look at the `java.time` package for the appropriate class for your use case.

Comment: Stop using the old, ugly Calendar. Use the java.time classes: int dayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getValue())

Comment: Of course you get 7 for a Saturday, because `Calendar.SATURDAY = 7`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY.

Answer (score 2):

That's consistent with [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#SATURDAY). The week starts on Sunday which has a value of 1.

Comment: Java 8 link: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY)

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that the op is on android (textView). Otherwise I would have recommended java.time.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal.

It starts from Sunday with 1... and ends on Saturday with 7.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intend to use [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#SATURDAY) instead.

> The singleton instance for the day-of-week of Saturday. This has the
>   numeric value of 6.

The code to retrieve this in java is already shared by @JB Nizet in comments:

```
int dayOfWeek = java.time.LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getValue();
```

and you can further convert it into `String` and set as the text of `textView` you're using in a similar manner.

Comment: Can't use `DayOfWeek` with `Calendar`.

Comment: @Andreas not suggesting to use it with `Calendar` anyway